# Duplicated records when using factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm having some hard times using rspec + factory-girl. Just for start, here are my code samples:

#### factories/users.rb

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |f|
    f.email { Faker::Internet.email }
    f.password "SamplePassword"
  end
end
```

#### factories/favourites.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :favourite do
    # `ex_products` table is an external sqlserver table 
    # and it can't be tested with factories cause 
    # there is just one production instance of it.
    ex_product_id 50136

    user
  end
end
```

#### spec/models/favourite_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Favourite do
  subject(:favourite) { FactoryGirl.build(:favourite) }

  it { expect(favourite).to be_valid }

  it "is invalid without a user" do
    favourite.user = nil
    expect(favourite).to be_invalid 
  end

  it "is invalid without a product" do
    favourite.ex_product = nil
    expect(favourite).to be_invalid
  end

  describe "#toggle_for_user" do
    context "when product is faved" do
      before(:all) do
        FactoryGirl.create(:favourite)
      end

      it "removes it from favourites" do
        product = favourite.ex_product
        user    = favourite.user
        Favourite.toggle_for_user(product, user)
        expect(Favourite.all).to be_nil
      end
    end

    context "when product is not faved" do
      it "adds it to favourites"
    end
  end
end
```

---

Now, the problem: When i'm testing `#toggle_for_user / "removes it from favourites"` part, i have two `User` records in my test database which makes my test fail in cause of user model validations and relations which are not mentioned here. However, they are not important, the only thing i need to know is **why there are two `User` records in the db** on `removes it from favourites` stage and what can i do with that. I can't find anything about it in factory_girl docs.

The command i'm using to run this test is:

> rspec spec/models/favourite_spec.rb

So that's the only test fired.

Thanks in advance for any clues!

Comment: First of all, I think `Favourite.all` will not be `nil` but empty array. Second, you are creating two `Favourite` objects: one on the top of `describe Favourite` block and another in `before :all` inside `context "when product is faved"` block

Comment: hmm, i'm using a `build()` method on the top of `describe Favourite` block. Does it also creates a new user in db? 

Yes, that `Favourite.all` part definatelly should be changed but my main problem now is that i have two users in the DB, nothing more ;)

Thaks for reply!

Comment: yes it does: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
subject(:favourite) { FactoryGirl.build(:favourite) }
```

This line builds and saves User instance and builds but does not save Favourite object by default. Check [the docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) below "Associations" header. Guess `strategy: :build` can help in your case.

Comment: In your favourites factory, use `association :user, strategy: :build` instead of just `user`.

Comment: @ArtemKalinchuk thank you, that saved me a ton of time